# GAE: find project name by project number

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have many GAE projects (more than 60) that I have to map, clean, delete part of them. For some projects I have only "Project number". Is there a way to find out "Project Name" or "Project Id" having "Project number" without going to each project and check it manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find Project ID with project number by running this command:

```
gcloud projects list \
   --filter='PROJECT_NUMBER=(PROJECT_NUMBER_1, ..., PROJECT_NUMBER_N)
```

Replace PROJECT_NUMBER_X with all the project numbers you have.

You can read more about filters and their syntaxis [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters).